# How to find cliques in a graph?

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ruby and the Ruby Graph Library  http://rgl.rubyforge.org/

How do I find all the cliques (complete subgraphs) in a graph?

Specifically, I'm looking for a 5 clique involving two particular vertices.

---

What I'm really up to - Project Euler [Problem 60](http://projecteuler.net/problem=60)

> The primes 3, 7, 109, and 673, are quite remarkable. By taking any two primes and concatenating them in any order the result will always be prime. For example, taking 7 and 109, both 7109 and 1097 are prime. The sum of these four primes, 792, represents the lowest sum for a set of four primes with this property.
>
> Find the lowest sum for a set of five primes for which any two primes concatenate to produce another prime.

My graph has vertices the prime numbers, with an edge from p to q if decimal concatenations 'pq' and 'qp' are both prime.

Comment: Do you realize it's an NP-complete problem to find the largest clique?

Comment: Algorithm-wise, finding a 5-clique in `O(v^5)` is pretty straightforward as long as you can iterate over the vertices and check if an edge is present.

Comment: Algorithm-wise, if two vertices are given, finding the remaining three is straightforward in `O(v^3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Specifically, I'm looking for a 5 clique involving two particular vertices.

Assuming those two vertices are `first` and `second`

```
common = ug.adjacent_vertices(first) & ug.adjacent_vertices(second)

for triple in common.combination(3)
    a,b,c = triple
    if ug.has_edge?(a,b) && ug.has_edge?(a,c) && ug.has_edge?(b,c)
        return [first,second,a,b,c]
```